# How do i remove the --gradient-background from this section so it stays white. (Shopify)

Tags: shopify

I have an image with text section on shopify. However as seen in the image it is showing the purple color at the sides, from inspect element I know it is coming from .color-background-1 {
--gradient-background: #d211d2 } However I do not know how to remove it.

[The image I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjDIM.png).

How do I remove it so that that part becomes white.

Thanks

I tried the custom css in the section customize by adding .color-background-1 {
--gradient-background: white } but it still did not work. What is the solution?